# pycharm can not open image file

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to code a python calculator ,here is my code

```
main.py:
import pygame
import os
import Item
global items


one = Item.Item('/images/numbers/1.png',       "1",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
two = Item.Item('/images/numbers/2.png',       "2",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
three = Item.Item('/images/numbers/3.png',       "3",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
four = Item.Item('/images/numbers/4.png',       "4",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
five = Item.Item('/images/numbers/5.png',       "5",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
six = Item.Item('/images/numbers/6.png',       "6",       200, 200) # here is where yo specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
seven = Item.Item('/images/numbers/7.png',       "7",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
eight = Item.Item('/images/numbers/8.jpg',       "8",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
nine = Item.Item('/images/numbers/9.png',       "9",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
ten = Item.Item('/images/numbers/0.jpg',       "0",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
plus = Item.Item('/images/sim/+.png',       "+",       200, 200)# here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
minus = Item.Item('/images/sim/-.png',       "-",       200, 200
```

and here is item.py:

```
import pygame
import os
global items

items = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Item(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    global hide

    # the constructor
    def __init__(self, img_name, name, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, items)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_name))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.name = name;
        self.hide = False

    # to display on game panel
    def display(self, surface):
        if self.hide == False:
            surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

but when i run it on pycharm it comes up with this :

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/main.py
pygame 1.9.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  File "/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    one = Item.Item('/images/numbers/1.png',       "1",       200, 200) # here is where you specify the image file name ( must be exact!)
  File "/Users/oscar/Desktop/python_calculator/Item.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_name))
pygame.error: Couldn't open /images/numbers/1.png

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have pygame download and i have tried to run somebody else's code with is very similar and it works an not find out out why
Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the image files are at `/images/numbers/`, and that you didn't miss adding a base path to that when using `os.path.join`?

Comment: Are you sure that the image file `/images/numbers/1.png` exists on your system?  The most straightforward explanation is that it does not. - As @TheGamer007 says, should you be passing a base path to your `join()` call?  As it is now, the `join()` call isn't doing anything.

Comment: thanks for replying . it definitely exists in finder

Comment: If all you want is to create an Image object, you can try using `PIL` library

Comment: Remove the starting `/` from the path. This makes it absolute and I am assuming you have a folder called `images` under your code folder

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue to you and I've found the solution. 
I believe that this mainly to do with how the virtual environment runs your application. Simply put, it runs it in a different directory. Here's the solution:

1. [Click on the "Edit Configuration" button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPg8S.png)
2. [Edit the path in the highlighted box. (For my own project, I just removed the \venv path.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLfFN.png)

I hope this helps!

Comment: well, it didn't help, do you have any other options to try?

Comment: In response to bit_scientist, no, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the image in the same project file as the code you are working with. I hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

since python support only .gif extension of file so change the file format.

Comment: What does that mean *Python support only .gif extension*? There are different libraries in Python to handle images which have their own restrictions. `pygame` specifically [might support](https://web.archive.org/web/20200510124054/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) other formats